# String formatting problem Java

Tags: java

im trying to format this string into a fixed column style but cant get it to work, heres my code, whats up?

```
System.out.format("%32s%10n%32s%10n%32s%10n", "Voter: " + e.voteNo + "Candidate: " + vote + "Booth: " + boothId);
```

All variables are integers,

I want the output to be like

```
Voter: 1    Candidate: 0     Booth: 1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please stop trying to program by accident. Your code looks like the glued-together parts of 3 different approaches to solving the issue. Try to read the documentation on the topic (JavaDoc is your friend!) and apply what you learned instead.

```
String result = String.format("Voter: %-10d Candidate: %-10d Booth: %-10d", e.voteNo, vote, boothId);
System.out.println(result);
```

For more information on [`String.format` check its JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29).

Edit: apparently I didn't get the memo that there's actually a [`PrintStream.format`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29), so you can actually write it like this:

```
System.out.format("Voter: %-10d Candidate: %-10d Booth: %-10d", e.voteNo, vote, boothId);
```

Comment: @sje397: yes, I just realized. The glueing-together part still applies, as he's mixing string concatenation with format and wrong format definitions (`%n` is a newline in Java and not a numeric format).